# URL rewrite issues using .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to write a URL like below, but when I try to call the seo queryparam, it always returns index.php.  Any idea why it isn't returning the correct value for 'seo'?

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ index.php?c=home&m=details&seo=$1 [L]
```

The URL it should forward from would be something like this: http://domain.com/The-Name-of-the-Product. That URL should be rewritten to http://domain.com/index.php?c=home&m=details&seo=The-Name-of-the-Product, but instead it ends up as http://domain.com/index.php?c=home&m=details&seo=index.php

Comment: What's the correct value? What URLs are actually meant to be matched by this rule? It doesn't look like there are many which could match (mostly /, //, ///, etc). Did you want a .* instead of just a * perhaps?

Comment: The URL it would forward to should be something like this: http://domain.com/The-Name-of-the-Product

Comment: Are you putting the RewriteRule in .htaccess or an httpd.conf file? What other RewriteRules do you have defined (please post them in order)?

Comment: The RewriteRule is in .htaccess

Comment: The descriptions of the behavior you want and the behavior you get could be a little clearer. Is it correct that you want `http://domain.com/The-Name-of-the-Product` to be rewritten to `http://domain.com/index.php?c=home&m=details&seo=The-Name-of-the-Product`, but it ends up as `http://domain.com/index.php`?

Comment: outis, your are partly correct. The URL gets written to the product detail page correctly (http://domain.com/index.php?c=home&m=details&seo=The-Name-of-the-Product), but the seo queryparam is always equal to 'index.php'.  Why when i call the seo  query param would it be passing back index.php instead of 'The-Name-of-the-Product'?

Comment: There's the value of being precise and informative, right there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Various events cause a URL to go back through the rewrite process. You can use [RewriteCond](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond) to prevent this:

```
RewriteCond $1 !^index.php$
RewriteRule ^/?([^/]+)$ index.php?c=home&m=details&seo=$1 [L,NS]
```

From the [mod_rewrite technical details](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/rewrite/rewrite_tech.html):

> When you manipulate a URL/filename in per-directory context mod_rewrite first rewrites the filename back to its corresponding URL (which is usually impossible, but see the RewriteBase directive below for the trick to achieve this) and then initiates a new internal sub-request with the new URL. This restarts processing of the API phases.

This catches people all the time.

Comment: beat me to it, but that is it exactly! +1

Comment: I did find one issue.  My domain does not work with out entering index.php in to the URL now.  http://domain.com does not work.  It just takes me to a blank white page.  Any ideas?

Comment: Change the '*' metacharacter to a '+' so that the URL has at least one character in the path. Answer updated.